# OpenXML Update/Write to Excel Cell (even if it is null)

Tags: c#, excel, openxml

I have a XLSX Excel document that I am updating using OpenXML 2.5.  Understandably, some cells are more difficult to update since they currently are null.  The method below returns null for GetCell when the cell value is null, and therefore I am unable to proceed with a cell update.

Is there any all-in-one method (or additional library) which will update a cell, even if it is null?

**Edit**: I've been having various problems using OpenXML, so in the meantime I started using [ClosedXML](https://closedxml.codeplex.com) instead, and in every scenario ClosedXML works perfectly.

```
public static void UpdateCell(string docName, string text,
        uint rowIndex, string columnName)
    {
        // Open the document for editing.
        using (SpreadsheetDocument spreadSheet =
                 SpreadsheetDocument.Open(docName, true))
        {
            WorksheetPart worksheetPart =
                  GetWorksheetPartByName(spreadSheet, "Sheet1");

            if (worksheetPart != null)
            {
                Cell cell = GetCell(worksheetPart.Worksheet,
                                         columnName, rowIndex);

                cell.CellValue = new CellValue(text);
                cell.DataType =
                    new EnumValue<CellValues>(CellValues.Number);

                // Save the worksheet.
                worksheetPart.Worksheet.Save();
            }
        }

    }


 private static Cell GetCell(Worksheet worksheet,
              string columnName, uint rowIndex)
    {
        Row row = GetRow(worksheet, rowIndex);

        if (row == null) return null;

        var FirstRow = row.Elements<Cell>().Where(c => string.Compare
               (c.CellReference.Value, columnName +
               rowIndex, true) == 0).FirstOrDefault();

        if (FirstRow == null) return null;

        return FirstRow;
    }
```